# cordova-plugin-dialogs prevent "click" outside

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using cordova-plugin-dialogs plugin for my mobile app. The dialog can be displayed via something like this:

```
$cordovaDialogs.confirm('We could not reach the server. Please try again.', 'Network Problem', ['Cancel','Retry'])
    .then(function(buttonIndex) {
        if(buttonIndex==2){
            checkNetwork();
        }else{
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
});
```

It works, but the problem is when user "click" outside the dialog, the dialog will disappear and trigger the result of `0` and the app will exit. How can I disable ability to "click" outside of the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin works that way, you'll have to fork the plugin, change the behaviour and install your fork instead of the official plugin.

There is a few lines that allows to cancel the dialog when you press outside, you'll have to change them from

```
dlg.setCancelable(true);
```

to

```
dlg.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the proposed solution from @jcesarmobile didn't work, but [this](https://github.com/SRBConsultingTeam/cordova-plugin-dialogs/commit/88e4aa6d90f65111ea90405fc96bd4ebb025765d)

works.

Just set 

`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`